# Font Rendering Error

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I only have this issue with google chrome, everything is displayed okay in firefox. As you can see in the picture, the string of characters is not displayed correctly. Please tell me how to fix it. Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your chrome.
Go on advanced settings, in language section, You will find an web content section.
In this, You can change the encoding font option, try to septup as default or find your encoding font country option, in France, where i am it's utf-8.

New 
In your menu, go to tools, and select Encoding.
Did the autodetect is on ? Perhaps try to disable if on, or enable if on.
Or select Western encoding option.

Comment: It is still the same. I think your suggestion should have fixed the problem. But it didn't. Weird.

Comment: I edit my answer with new solution perhaps.

Comment: I don't see anything like you described